# Animation on element not applied

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

I have a react component in which I append some elements dynamically:

```
addElement( reactComponent, imgurl, e, layer ) {
    const elementWrapper = document.createElement( 'span' );
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const element = document.createElement( 'img' );
    const [ x, y ] = this.getMousePositionInsideTheElement( banner, e );

    elementWrapper.style.position = 'absolute';
    elementWrapper.id = layer.name;

    element.src = imgurl;
    element.onload = function () {

        element.classList.add( layer.name.split('.')[0] );
        element.style.height = '50px';
        element.style.width = '50px';
        elementWrapper.style.top = `${y - 50 / 2 }px`;
        elementWrapper.style.left = `${x - 50 / 2}px`;

        element.onclick = () => dispatch( setSelectedLayer( layer ) );

        elementWrapper.appendChild( element );
        reactComponent.appendChild( elementWrapper )
    }
}
```

based on the user input, I create dynamically a `style` element and append it on the `head`

`updateScene( stylesheet )
    {
        let style = document.createElement( 'style' );
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = getCSS( stylesheet );
        document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ].appendChild( style );
    }`

The element's css properties are correctly updated, and the element is updated as well e.g. if the user change the height and the width, I generate a new css and append it on the head, the css rules are correctly applied and the element in the "Scene" is updated. But that is not happening with the `animations`, although they seem correct ( they work on Codepen ).

My generated css is like:

```
img.CZ6kGtDWwAAcrG4 {
  height: 200px;
  widht: 200px;
}

.CZ6kGtDWwAAcrG4 {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  border-top-width: 10px;
  animation-name: cz6kgtdwwaacrg4-octopus-animation;
  animation-iteration-count: 15;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes cz6kgtdwwaacrg4-octopus-animation {
  9% {
    border-top-style: solid;
  }

  42% {
    border-top-style: solid;
  }

  70% {
    border-top-width: 30px;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-top-style: solid;
  }
}
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see it as a demo please? It would help in debugging.

Comment: @Harry finally I solved it. I used `React.createElement` instead of `document.createElement` and then `map` inside of the component instead of `append`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to solve the issue using React.createElement instead of document.createElement**

```
    const reactElementOptions = {
        style: {
            height: '50px',
            width: '50px'
        },
        className: layer.name.split('.')[0],
        src: imgurl
    };

    const reactElement = React.createElement( 'img', reactElementOptions );

    const reactElementWrapperOptions = {
        id: layer.name,
        style: {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: y,
            left: x
        },
        onClick: () => dispatch( setSelectedLayer( layer ) )
    };
    const reactElementWrapper = React.createElement( 'span', reactElementWrapperOptions, reactElement );

    this.state.elements.push( reactElementWrapper );

    this.setState( {
        elements: this.state.elements
    } );
```

And then `map` inisde the component instead of `append`

```
            {
                this.state.elements.map( ( el ) => el )
            }
```